# Targeting cities with meteors (part 2)

Tags: space, hard-science, meteor

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/targeting-cities-with-meteors) asked about aliens launching meteors at major metropolitan areas on Earth, but explicitly excluded the accuracy of the meteors from the question.

> In this specific scenario aliens are using asteroids from our asteroid belt and launching them at earth to target specific cities. Never mind how they target (unless it is relevant to your answer) so accurately.

I'm interested in the **targeting** part of this question.  How accurately could you hit a city on Earth with an asteroid from the belt?

Assumptions about the city are the same as the previous question:

> - 450 sq miles of land area
> - Generally flat land area, no more than 500 feet min/max elevation change
> - Essentially I want a city destroyed but I don't want regional/global firestorms or cooling.

Another assumption:  Once the asteroid is initially accelerated, no further course corrections can be made.  This is an unguided, unpowered projectile.

Comment: If a species has the means to freely manipulate the path of a small celestial body, they can probably aim it with at least as good precision as we can do today with missiles. I'll let someone better versed write up an answer about it, though.

Comment: Seconding Frostfyre's comment, but not enough for an answer, I imagine the problem will be to apply sufficient delta-v to the asteroid to slam it into the Earth *at all*, rather than once you have that capability how to aim accurately enough to hit an approximately 20x20 miles area on the ground. Consider how accurately we were able to send [Rosetta and Philae to 67P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/67P/Churyumov%E2%80%93Gerasimenko#Exploration), or New Horizons to Pluto. It's all about accurate delta-v and orbital calculations; I know the saying is cliché, but that's hardly rocket science.

Comment: @Frostfyre - Missiles are self-guided, though.  Rockets aren't, and they're definitely less accurate (although still generally good).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - As with the missile comparison, those were both powered spacecraft.  An asteroid wouldn't be able to make course corrections.  I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: With a decent model of the original orbit, and a well-enough known imparted delta-v (change in velocity), midcourse corrections should be avoidable. Most often in practice the problem is the accuracy of orbit and delta-v, but I think if a civilization is capable of moving asteroids around at will, they will likely have good enough models that imprecision in those are not going to pose major problems. Unpowered cruise spaceflight is, relatively speaking, trivially predictable. Not really paper-and-pencil trivial, but even early computers could make the calculations quickly enough to be useful.

Comment: Aliens that are capable of getting to the solar system but can't bring their own nukes with them? Hate to be that guy, but seems odd that any one technologically capable of travelling across the stars would not bring their own ammo.

Comment: The issue with unpowered object is the fact that the Solar system is full of shifting gravitational fields, making a simple calculation of trajectories virtually impossible with current methods. This is a variation of the "three body problem", which cannot be solved exactly. So while a meteor or asteroid could be launched at Earth, it will experience subtle or perhaps not so subtle displacements in its path, leading to cumulative errors. This is why spacecraft do mid course corrections, to identify and rectify errors in the flight path.

Comment: @Thucydides Fair enough, but nudging an asteroid onto a collision course with Earth isn't exactly trivial with current technology *either*. So I think we can safely assume that any civilization capable of pulling off this stunt is going to have vastly more advanced technology than we do at their disposal, and be willing to throw some work at the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Thucydides is getting at the issue I'm having with the "it's trivial" answer.  Nudging something so that it *hits Earth* isn't necessarily hard.  After all, Earth has a gravity well and will capture anything that comes too close at too slow a speed.  But I'm not asking about hitting the 8000-mile-diameter Earth, I'm asking about hitting a specific 20-mile wide plot of land on one side of it.  That requires *far* more precision.

Answer (score 1):

$\Large{Yes.}$

Just throw it on a Hohmann transfer orbit, which is the delta-v minimizing transfer between wherever it is and Los Angeles. The energy formula is trivial:

Let:

$ v \,\!$ be the speed of an orbiting body,
$\mu = GM\,\!$ be the standard gravitational parameter of the primary body, assuming M+m is not significantly bigger than M (which makes $ v_M \ll v$),
$ r \,\!$ is the distance of the orbiting body from the primary focus, and,
$a \,\!$ is the semi-major axis of the body's orbit.

Then:
$$\Delta v_1 
= \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r_1}}
  \left( \sqrt{\frac{2 r_2}{r_1+r_2}} - 1 \right)$$

Since you can also calculate the timing to any arbitrary precision using:

$$t_H 
= \begin{matrix}\frac12\end{matrix} \sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2 a^3_H}{\mu}}
= \pi \sqrt{\frac {(r_1 + r_2)^3}{8\mu}}$$

...you can most definitely time it with the known orbital and rotational parameters of Earth's motion to target Los Angeles.

After all, primitive earth-people were able to target one of their probes into a 100x100 km window as part of a slingshot maneuver around Jupiter with 21st century technology.

Since the object will likely be in the megaton range to raze anything the size of a metropolis, you will likely need a fusion-powered mass driver on the impactor surface. Given that the energy will not be instantaneous, the actual calculations will require integral calculus, but are still rather trivial.

Good luck!